# File existence in internal storage using java

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application were i am reading the content from a file present in internal storage and displaying in the application.
I am creating a file on the desktop and transferring that file to the mobile using usb cable.If sdcard is present the file will be stored in sdcard and for accessing the file i found the following code and it worked for me.

```
File  path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

/storage/sdcard0/Filename.txt is the path which i am getting when i run the above code.If file is present in sdcard it is returning true else false.

If sdcard is not present and when i transfer the file from desktop to mobile it gets stored in internal storage.in this case how do i access my file.
In some cases i have come to know that sdcard0 is internal storage and not the external storage.

Which is the best way to find the file existence in internal storage of the mobile and not apps internal storage. please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To find out the path for your app's internal storage you can use the following commands:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
or
Context context = getApplication(); 

String dir = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
String dir = context.getFilesDir().getPath();
```

getFilesDir() returns a File object that you can get the path from there. Then you can use that path to transfer your file. Also read below.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) on how to write a file to internal storage and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) on getting the path for internal storage.

The following code gives you the path for the your file in internal storage and then you can open it:

```
String yourFilePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "filename";
File yourFile = new File( yourFilePath );
```

You can also use the following approach explained in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

```
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fileContent.append(new String(buffer));
}
```

The above solution opens input stream to the file name provided using the context that gives the location where the files are stored in internal storage. In the while loop it reads from the input stream (up to size of buffer) every iterator and adds the read data to StringBuilder instance. The loop terminates when the length of the read data from input stream is -1.

If the file is not found, FileNotFoundException will be throw by openFileInput(filename) method.

Comment: i have seen this before . I am juz transferring a file from desktop to mobile.I want to get that path

Comment: if you do System.out.println(context.getFilesDir().getPath()); what do you get?

Comment: I know how to read once file is present.But i am trying to find only file existence

Comment: You need to get the application context and then trigger getFilesDir() on that context. I have updated my answer, see above. Add the line that gets the application context then the other lines and then print the dir to see what is the path.

Comment: I have known about this before that files get stored in the application path only.When i use the above code file not exists is returning even though file exists in internal storage.

Comment: data/data/com.example.eth/files/Filename.txt is returned as the your file.

Comment: When i see the path of the file in the mobile it is showing a                 /internal Storage/Filename.txt. I want to get this path using the code.Is that possible.

Comment: Mobile will not show you all the packages and just gives you the idea that your file is stored in internal storage. The only way to get internal storage is to use context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() or just like you commented above it is /data/data/{packagename}/files/yourfilename this is the path that you are looking for.

Comment: What do you use to transfer your file from desktop to the mobile? do you use adb or some other tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95919/discussion-between-raf-and-sup).

Comment: I am juz transfering the file using usb cable,same as how we transfer images or songs.